# Swift compiler crashed When I include a large C array in a bridging header

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project that is using a mixture of C++, objective C, and Swift (4.1).

I have a header file called `cross_platform_structs.h`, and I define a struct as so:

```
#ifndef cross_platform_structs_h
#define cross_platform_structs_h

typedef struct {

    int size;
    float points[76800][3];
    float other_number;
    float number;
}Result;

#endif /* cross_platform_structs_h */
```

My bridging header has `#include "cross_platform_structs.h"`.

Since adding the `float points[76800][3]` the swift compiler crashes. I need to have this field now, so that I can export some data back from C++, into Swift.

Before I had the float array I had no problems. I've experimented with size, and it seems that the compiler is fine with an array of size `10000 x 3` floats, but it does take a long time to run.

When the crash occurs I get this error message:

`0x17c7ef880: i64 = TargetConstant<0>
In function: _T016ios_recorder_app15VideoSerializerCAC10Foundation4DataV05depthG0_AF05videoG0Sd2gxSd2gySd2gzSC13simd_float3x3V0H10IntrinsicsSC12VolumeResultV06volumeQ0tcfC
0  swift                    0x0000000110ecc36a PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x0000000110ecb7a6 SignalHandler(int) + 662
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff51ff9f5a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ffee244ca28 _sigtramp + 2420452072
4  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff51e24312 abort + 127
5  swift                    0x000000010d825a57 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*)::$_0::__invoke(void*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) + 551
6  swift                    0x0000000110e89adb llvm::report_fatal_error(llvm::Twine const&, bool) + 571
7  swift                    0x0000000110e89c91 llvm::report_fatal_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool) + 33
8  swift                    0x000000010f3031d9 llvm::SelectionDAGISel::SelectCodeCommon(llvm::SDNode*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) + 20409
9  swift                    0x000000010efcc30d (anonymous namespace)::AArch64DAGToDAGISel::Select(llvm::SDNode*) + 7437
10 swift                    0x000000010f2f84d5 llvm::SelectionDAGISel::CodeGenAndEmitDAG() + 2901
11 swift                    0x000000010f2f56b2 llvm::SelectionDAGISel::SelectAllBasicBlocks(llvm::Function const&) + 12226
12 swift                    0x000000010f2f17ef llvm::SelectionDAGISel::runOnMachineFunction(llvm::MachineFunction&) + 1775
13 swift                    0x000000010f6a4976 llvm::MachineFunctionPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 134
14 swift                    0x0000000110e0d18a llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 506
15 swift                    0x0000000110e0cd73 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 67
16 swift                    0x0000000110e15e50 llvm::legacy::PassManager::run(llvm::Module&) + 1264
17 swift                    0x000000010d9a4f19 swift::performLLVM(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::DiagnosticEngine*, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false>*, llvm::GlobalVariable*, llvm::Module*, llvm::TargetMachine*, swift::version::Version const&, llvm::StringRef, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 8425
18 swift                    0x000000010d82a4ce performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 19054
19 swift                    0x000000010d8241f4 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 7716
20 swift                    0x000000010d7d8e78 main + 12248
21 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff51d78115 start + 1
22 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000006e start + 2921889626`

Is there an upper limit to the memory I can use in a `Swift` array? Are there any measures I can take to get around this?

Comment: Swift doesn't have fixed-sized arrays, so C's fixed-size arrays are instead imported as tuples. `float points[76800][3]` would be imported as `var points: ((Float, Float, Float), (Float, Float, Float), ... , (Float, Float, Float))`, with 76800 nested tuples. Not surprising that such a large data type would crash the compiler

Comment: Ah, I can see that would be problematic. What's the best way to declare a cross-platform data type with a large size for use between Swift, C++ and objective c? I'm a Swift beginner.

Comment: Well I wouldn't recommend having such a large datatype in C. That Result struct is 91.2 KB! I would suggest you use dynamically allocated storage instead of a fixed size (stack allocated) aray